# I can't figure out why my animation for my dropout menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, animation, menu, onclick, height

I'm making a dropout menu for my website. My result has to be: if I click on the image, the dropout menu has to appear. I want an animation so I set the height 0px and after the javascript to 'auto'. Also I added an animation of 0.3s. The problem is that I see no animation. I hope that somebody could help me :)

HTML:

```
<div id="dropMenuNavBar">
<ul>
    <li> PORTFOLIO </li>
    <li> ABOUT ME </li>
    <li> CONTACT </li>
</ul>

<img onclick="dropMenuBar()" src="dropMenu.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
dropMenuNavBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 50;
    margin-top: 70px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function dropMenuBar() {
    document.getElementById('dropMenuNavBar').style.height= 'auto';
}
```

Comment: In your CSS: `#dropMenuNavBar` (you forgot the `#`). Change `overflow-x` to `overflow-y`. Close the div after the `</ul>` or the image gets hidden, too. Then change `'auto'` to a fixed height like `'230px'` or the transition won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `height` into 100%. Animations doesn't work on `auto` settings.

```js
var height = window.innerHeight;

function dropMenuBar() {
  document.getElementById('dropMenuNavBar').style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

```css
#dropMenuNavBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50;
  margin-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropMenuNavBar">
  <ul>
    <li> PORTFOLIO </li>
    <li> ABOUT ME </li>
    <li> CONTACT </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <img onclick="dropMenuBar()" src="http://placehold.it/620x150">
```

Comment: @Soccerlife There is an animation when clicking on the image. The menu is scrolling down.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now! The only small problem yet is that the height of my DropoutMenu varies for each screen, so a fixed height is not really what i want

Comment: @Soccerlife You can always check the screen height with javascript and then set the height of the menu. I've edited my post, check it.

Comment: @Soccerlife Thank you. Cheers!:)